# Query Couchdb by date while maintaining sort order

Tags: couchdb

I am new to couchdb, i have looked at the docs and SO posts but for some reason this simple query is still eluding me.

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM x WHERE DATE BETWEEN startdate AND enddate ORDER BY score
```

> UPDATE: **It cannot be done**.  This is unfortunate since to get this type
>   of data you have to pull back potentially millions of records (a few
>   fields) from couch then do either filtering, sorting or limiting
>   yourself to get the desired results.  I am now going back to my
>   original solution of using [_changes](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html) to capture and store elsewhere the data i do need to perform that query on.

Here is my **updated** view (thanks to Dominic):

```
emit([d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth() + 1, d.getUTCDate(), score], doc.name);
```

What I need to do is:

- Always sort by score descending
- Optionally filter by date range (for instance, TODAY only)
- Limit by x

> Update: Thanks to Dominic I am much closer - but still having an
>   issue.

```
?startkey=[2017,1,13,{}]&endkey=[2017,1,10]&descending=true&limit=10&include_docs=true
```

This brings back documents between the dates sorted by score

However if i want top 10 regardless of date then i only get back top 10 sorted by date (and not score)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, when using complex keys in CouchDB, you can **only** sort from left to right. This is a common misconception, but read up on [Views Collation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/collation.html) for a more in-depth explanation. (while you're at it, read the entire [Guide to Views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/index.html) as well since you're getting started)

If you want to be able to sort by score, but filter by *date* only, you can accomplish this by breaking down your timestamp to only show the degree you care about.

```
function (doc) {
  var d = new Date(doc.date)
  emit([ d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth() + 1, d.getUTCDate(), score ])
}
```

You'll end up outputting a more complex key than what you currently have, but you query it like so:

```
startkey=[2017,1,1]&endkey=[2017,1,1,{}]
```

This will pick out all the documents on 1-1-2017, and it'll be sorted by score already! (in ascending order, simply swap `startkey` and `endkey` to get descending order, no change to the view needed)

As an aside, avoid emitting the entire `doc` as the value in your view. It is likely more efficient to leverage the `include_docs=true` parameter, and leaving the value of your emit empty. (please refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36210507/why-is-the-couchdb-documentation-suggesting-docs-should-not-be-emitted-in-the-vi) for more information)

With this exact setup, you'd need separate views in order to query by different precisions. For example, to query by month you just use the year/month and so on.

However, if you are willing/able to sort your scores in your application, you can use a single view to get all the date precision you want. For example:

```
function (doc) {
  var d = new Date(doc.date)
  emit([ d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth() + 1, d.getUTCDate(), d.getUTCHour(), d.getUTCMinutes(), d.getUTCSeconds(), d.getUTCMilliseconds() ])
}
```

With this view and the `group_level` parameter, you can get all the scores by year, month, date, hour, etc. As I mentioned, in this case it won't be sorted by score yet, but maybe this opens up other queries to you. (eg: what users participated this month?)

Comment: Great, thank you Dominic I am about to try this out now.  

I was not actually storing the doc, but a newly create subset of the doc (with 8 props) (ie: { Name: doc.prop.name, ...} - would it still be more efficient to use include_docs=true (and view = emit([keys],1) when the doc has about 50 properties?  I can measure but sounds like you would know off the top of your head :-)

Comment: I also updated my question after finding out that limit can really effect things - but your solution works perfectly for all needs - thanks so much!

Comment: I spoke too soon. If i add limit then its not working correctly due to the left-right sorting.   I updated my question. (and edited my comment for the 100th time, sorry for all of the updates)

Comment: Remember, you can only sort from left to right, so you can't get TOP 10 over the arbitrary date range you've set. (you _can_ get the top 10 from a single date though)

Comment: Yes, when i first read your post "This is a common misconception" i thought you were saying that is not true.  Too bad.